# What is a "upper intake cleaning" and do I really need to do it

Tags: engine, ford, maintenance, scheduled-maintenance

I took my '06 ford ranger (140k miles) to the shop after it was misfiring badly. They informed me that I need new plugs/wires and a new coil pack. They also wanted to sell me a upper intaking cleaning. What is this and is it reallly necessary?

Comment: I'd guess that they want to clean your intake manifold. The intake can soot in it, due to the EGR valve introducing exhaust into the intake, which can make some sensors not work quite right. (I'm not sure of the sensor configuration on your car - it might not have problems with soot like some do.) I'd recommend asking exactly what they mean by "upper intake cleaning," because I've never specifically heard that terminology used before.

Comment: I would also assume the "upper intake" is easier to get to and likely to be more profitable. I would guess it's one of the "while we're in there" type jobs that some shops like to do. Did they cite a reason for this procedure? A quick look at Google and I don't see any conversation on this topic. I would assume there would be some if the issue was common. Google also says you have a one-piece intake manifold.

Comment: Depending on how thorough a job they do it will also clean intake valves and combustion chambers, yes it is worth it, if done properly.